# Polymer Event listener extract data

Tags: polymer, addeventlistener

How to set list which is of parent element with this subscription data.?
Don't want to alter or add attribute to subscription element as it's independent of parent.

I got polymer element structure like this:

```
<polymer-element name="parent">
 <polymer-element name="subscription" id="subscription">
 <polymer-element>
  <div id="list">
    <template repeat="{{item in list}}">
      <item name="{{item}}">
      </item>
    </template>
  </div>
 <script>
  Polymer('parent', {
    ready: function() {
     this.list = this.list || [];
     subscribe = this.$.subscription;

//Anytime if there is any change in subscription it send the data. 

     subscribe.addEventListener('data_from_subscription_element', function(x) {

      // How to set list which is of parent element with this subscription data.?
      // Don't want to alter or add attribute to subscription element as it's independent of parent.  

       this.data;
     });
    }
  });
 </script>
<polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like common problem of changing scope you are in. Try this:

```
<script>
  Polymer('parent', {
    ready: function() {
      var that = this; // Giving the current scope to that;

      this.list = this.list || [];
      subscribe = this.$.subscription;

      subscribe.addEventListener('data_from_subscription_element', function(x) {
        that.list = this.data; // Using that here 
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm still quiet naive to JS.